# Can I use Or operator in a regular expression for validating an input?

Tags: regex

I'm learning how to use the regular expressions for validating user inputs. I'm using Jquery to do it. I just want to know if it's possible to use an OR operator inside the expression.

I want to validate if the string has:

- One letter first and then at least 6 digits

OR

- First, at least 6 digits and then one letter

Examples :

```
X123456... OR 123456P
```

I use this `/^[a-zA-Z]\d{6}/` for the first one but can I use something like this to take in consideration both conditions ?

```
/^[a-zA-Z]\d{6}/ | /^\d{6}/[a-zA-Z] ??
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nearly got it:

```
/^(?:[a-zA-Z]\d{6,}|\d{6,}[a-zA-Z])/
```

`|` is the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Comment: Shouldn't the first part also be `\d{6,}` (i.e. "at least six")?

Comment: @mart1n, if this is "wrong" depends on what the OP wanted to do with the result. If he is reusing the matched part and needs all digits, then yes. So, I will add it.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions have an *alternative* operator, which uses the same `|` symbol. You just need to put it inside the regexp:

```
/^([a-z]\d{6}|\d{6}[a-z])/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure, you're pretty much there:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]\d{6}|\d{6}[a-zA-Z])/
```